# Returning an object but not using the new keyword, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create an object that gets returned without the `new` keyword in javascript?

My code structure so far;

```
myLib.func = (function() {

    "use strict";

    function func() {

        this._init();
    };

    func.prototype._init = function() {

        this.someVar = 5;
    };

    Return func;

})();
```

This obviously only works when using the `new` keyword;

```
new myLib.func();
```

How can I make it so that I can just do;

```
var func = myLib.func();
```

But it would still return an object that is exactly the same as the first example?

**What I have tried**

```
myLib.func = (function() {

    "use strict";

    function func() {

        if (window === this) {
            return new myLib.func();
        } else {
            this._init();
        }
    };

    func.prototype._init = function() {

        this.someVar = 5;
    };

    Return func;

})();
```

This does not work I learned from an example on slide 25 of John Resig's tips on building a library, http://ejohn.org/blog/building-a-javascript-library/

I know there are already existing frameworks, but rolling my own will make me learn alot, and as you can see that isn't alot at the moment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), the `this` will be `undefined` by default. You can account for this feature by adding it to your condition:

```
    if (window === this || undefined === this) {
        return new myLib.func();
    } else {
        this._init();
    }
```

or by checking whether the current object is an instance of the constructor (using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)):

```
    if (this instanceof func) {
        this._init();
    } else {
        return new func();
    }
```

(PS. You've got a typo in your code; JavaScript is case-sensitive, so you should use `return` instead of `Return` at the end)

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you alot :) I think I will use the second example it is more concise and easier to read! Thanks for the typo tip

Comment: @user2251919 One last thing, I would just write `new func();` instead of `new myLib.func();`. By doing this, the code becomes more portable. For instance, if you decide to rename `myLib`, or re-assign `myLib.func`, then the code will still behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If `myLib.func` is your class name, you cannot call it like `var func = myLib.func();`.
However, you could wrap this latter into another function, such that you get

```
var factory = function(){
    var func = myLib.func();
    return func;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need public / private methods, you can use object literal

```
var myLib = {}; 
myLib.func = {
     _init: function() {
         this.someVar = 5;
     },
     doSomething: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
     }
};
```

This will be a singleton object, usually it's enough for javascript applciation. If you need many instances of an object, you'll be forced to put a "new" keyword somewhere.